# Problem in the array of my XML to mySQL script, I can not import more than one node

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am trying to import my XML to mySQL. However what I have now, adds only the first  (as the XML below). What I want and is not working, is to add a root element in the XML and other . 
I don't mind if the code is localized to the exact fields I use.

The name of the table is *xml2msql* and the fields are *to, from, heading, body*.

If you have your very own code that will work, that would be great if you share it with me.

The code below is kind of globalized if your xml elements and mysql fields are the same and in the same order.

```
$columns = array();
$data = array();
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");
echo $xml->getName() . "<br />";
foreach($xml->children() as $child)
  {
  echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br />";
  $columns[] = $child->getName();
  $data[] = (string)$child;

  }

$col = '`'. implode('`,`',$columns) .'`';
$val = "'". implode("','",$data)."'";
$query = "INSERT INTO xml2mysql ($col) VALUES ($val)";
echo $query;
mysql_query($query);
```

this is the xml that works with the code above

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Dont forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

and this is the preferable xml

```
<notes>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Dont forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
<note>
<to>Mary</to>
<from>Nick</from>
<heading>Letter</heading>
<body>Reminder about your dog</body>
</note>
<notes>
```

Comment: *(tip)* http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2006/03/importing-xml-data-into-mysql-using.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through each note like this:

```
foreach($xml->note as $note)
{
    $columns = array();
    $data = array();
    foreach($note->children() as $child)
    {
        echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br />";
        $columns[] = $child->getName();
        $data[] = (string)$child;
    }
    $col = '`'. implode('`,`',$columns) .'`';
    $val = "'". implode("','",$data)."'";
    $query = "INSERT INTO xml2mysql ($col) VALUES ($val)";
    echo $query;
}
```

I tried this with the XML you provided and it does the trick.

Comment: Thank you for this, it works great! If I remove the columns array and anything related to it, and do the query like `INSERT INTO xml2mysql (to,from,heading,body)` will I gain anything in performance, or the columns array is a must ?

Comment: Any time, glad I could help. I think you may as well hard code the columns in as if the XML changes in the future your script will try to add data to columns that don't exist in your table with will cause issues.

Comment: Matt, some of my data contains `'` that gives a sytnax error on mysql. How can I escape this ?

Comment: You can use the mysql_real_escape_string() function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: Thanks again. I changed it to this and works great now `$data[] = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$child);`